# SharePoint - saving and using custom built views across multiple libraries

Tags: document-library, list-view, custom-list

I am working in SharePoint 2013 and building out multiple (5, 6) libraries to store content.  I have a unique "view" that I created in the original library that I would like to replicate in the others without manually creating the view in each new library.  I have no coding background and not a SharePoint Design user.  Is there any straightforward way to save and use custom built views across multiple libraries?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No code way to get this done is to save the library as a template after creating your custom view and create new libraries from that template rather than the default template. If "Save as template" link is missing then use this link as workaround.

https://richardstk.com/2016/01/19/sharepoint-2013-save-document-library-as-template-missing/

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries are always the same and you have to do it on several environments, you can create the views creating a feature with the "FeatureActivated" event and using the .NET server API (SPView class)